# How do you fix "implicit instantiation" errors when compiling Mesos on OS X 10.9 Mavericks?

Tags: gcc, osx-mavericks, mesos

After upgrading to OS X Mavericks, running `make` in my Mesos build directory results in errors:

```
google/protobuf/message.cc:130:60: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >'
  return ParseFromZeroCopyStream(&zero_copy_input) && input->eof();
                                                           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/iosfwd:108:28: note: template is declared here
    class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS basic_istream;
                           ^
google/protobuf/message.cc:135:67: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >'
  return ParsePartialFromZeroCopyStream(&zero_copy_input) && input->eof();
                                                                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/iosfwd:108:28: note: template is declared here
    class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS basic_istream;
                           ^
google/protobuf/message.cc:175:16: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >'
  return output->good();
               ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/iosfwd:110:28: note: template is declared here
    class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS basic_ostream;
```

I started with a clean build directory, re-ran `./bootstrap`, and ran `cd build && ../configure`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OS X Mavericks replaced the `gcc` command with [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/):

```
$ gcc
clang: error: no input files
```

However, Mesos currently expects to be compiled with the GNU Compiler Collection. You need to install GCC 4.7 with Homebrew and configure your build directory to use it. To be sure, start with an empty build directory:

```
# Install GCC 4.7
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install gcc47

# Configure Mesos build to use GCC
cd /path/to/mesos
rm -rf build
mkdir build
cd build
CC=gcc-4.7 CXX=g++-4.7 ../configure
```

Then you can run `make` like before.

Comment: Further, it appears that brew now supports using gcc-4.7 to install another keg-–protobuf240a in my case–-see https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/20251#issuecomment-28135292

Comment: As an update, Mesos does nowadays (since 0.17) support being built with clang. There are some caveats though, latest release of Xcode (5.1) which comes with clang 3.4 had problems building the Mesos Python egg. That has been fixed for Mesos 0.18rc5.

Answer (score 19):

For people who find this page while Googling error messages thrown up by some other software that depends on old versions of Google's `protobuf` libraries, here's another solution:

Modify the file `src/google/protobuf/message.cc` and add the line `#include <iostream>` after the opening comment block, right before all the rest of the `#include` lines. That one-line change was enough to enable me to compile `protoc` from `protobuf-2.4.1` with the command-line tools from XCode 7.3 on an El Capitan Mac.

Comment: While this doesn't answer the question above quite correctly, it was exactly the answer I was needing for my own issue. Thanks.